# A measure for kurtosis that takes into account sizes?

Tags: variance, anomaly-detection, kurtosis

I have a dataset of prescribing on drugs by region, across a calendar year. This is a complete population dataset. The raw data looks like this:

```
region,drug,prescription_count
C123,020201,340
C124,020201,75
C123,020202,980
C124,020202,400
...
```

I want to find the drugs that are not prescribed consistently across regions - the ultimate goal is to find drugs with regions that are interesting outliers.

In other words, for the full list of drugs (the two anti-depressants `020201` and `020202` in the example above, though in my real data there's about 3000 drugs) I'm interested in knowing whether the prescribing of `020201` is more or less "normal" than `020202`.

To complicate matters, the regions have different population sizes, so we can't just look at the raw `prescription_count` values (and we can't easily normalise for population, because different regional demographics have different general prescribing needs).

To compensate for this, I've calculated the *proportion* of prescriptions that the drug accounted for in each region, as a proportion of total prescribing in that region *on that drug class* (which encompasses many drugs of a similar class, e.g. `0202` is the anti-depressant drug class).

So now the data looks like this:

```
region,drug,drug_class,prescription_count,prescription_count_as_proportion_of_drug_class_in_region
C123,020201,0202,340,0.22
C124,020201,0202,75,0.23
C123,020202,0202,980,0.33
C124,020202,0202,400,0.46
...
```

If I compare these proportional values for each drug across regions, the distribution is typically normal.

Now I need to find an appropriate measure for "normalness", using the proportional value. I've been using kurtosis, which does produce generally sensible-looking results.

However, the problem with kurtosis on this measure is that it takes no account of overall region size: for me, a large region that is an outlier is more significant than a small region that is an outlier. (Some regions are 10x larger than others.)

Given all the above, is there a way I can compare "normalness" across different drugs? Basically, I want to find a measure like kurtosis, but that applies more weight to regions with an outlier proportion value when they are large regions, not small ones. Then I want to use this measure to compare each drug.